# ios7 use AGImagePickerController to display photo album but the photo display after Dozens of seconds

Tags: objective-c, ios7

This is part of the code, used to display system in the photo album
It 's work well in ios6. not ios7.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GridCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        CGRect frame = [AGImagePickerController itemRect];
        CGFloat leftMargin = frame.origin.x;
        for (AGIPCGridItem *gridItem in [self itemsForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath])
        {
            [gridItem setFrame:frame];
            UITapGestureRecognizer *selectionGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:gridItem action:@selector(tap)];
            selectionGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            [gridItem addGestureRecognizer:selectionGestureRecognizer];
            [selectionGestureRecognizer release];
            [cell addSubview:gridItem];

            frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + frame.size.width + leftMargin;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

the link of AGImagePickerController
https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController

Please help me! thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution by under code in file AGIPCAssetsController.m

```
- (void)loadAssets{

[self.assets removeAllObjects];

__block AGIPCAssetsController *blockSelf = self;
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 70000
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
#endif
    @autoreleasepool {
        [blockSelf.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (result == nil) 
            {
                return;
            }
            AGIPCGridItem *gridItem = [[AGIPCGridItem alloc] initWithAsset:result andDelegate:blockSelf];
            if ( blockSelf.imagePickerController.selection != nil && 
                [blockSelf.imagePickerController.selection containsObject:result])
            {
                gridItem.selected = YES;
            }
            [blockSelf.assets addObject:gridItem];
            [gridItem release];
        }];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [blockSelf reloadData];

    });
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 70000
 });
#endif

}
```

I'm not very sure whether this kind of treatment have problem? But,I test this code In both ios6 and ios7 and calculate the cost time of methods in dispatch_async in ipad2,about 500 photos use 0.4 second ..so i think get rid of this dispatch_aysnc Does not have a large impact!

Hope to useful,Best wishes!